# MySQL AJAX PHP Notification Module

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Can anyone help me with this code? I would like to convert this async ajax to sync ajax. How do I do it? Here is the code that is written below. The system just lags when I leave it for 20 mins without even doing anything. So, maybe the problem is within the code.

```
function addmsg20(type, msg, data) {
        $('#display20').html(data);

    }

    function waitForMsg20() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "liprintednotif.php",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(data) {
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(data.data.length > 0){
                    var res = data.data;
                    var printed = "<ul class='menu'>";
                $.each(res, function(k, v){
                    var empext = v.employee_ext;
                    if(empext == null){
                        empext = "";
                    }else{
                        empext = v.employee_ext;
                    }
                    printed += "<li>" +            
                        "<a href='#'>" +
                          "<h4>" +
                            " "+v.employee_fname + " " +                           
                               v.employee_mname+" "+v.employee_lname+" " +empext+ "<small>" +
                               v.status_desc+ "</small>" +"</h4>" + 
                          "<p>" + v.subj_name + "</p>" +
                        "</a></li>";

                })
                printed += "</ul>";
                }else{
                    printed = "";
                }
                addmsg20("new", data.count, printed);
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg20,
                    1000);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                addmsg20("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg20,
                    15000);
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

        waitForMsg20();

    });
```

I am completely new to Javascript and/or AJAX so I really need help about this.

Comment: If you don't want it to be asynchronous, you can turn the "async" option to false

Comment: i tried that already, it doesn't work.

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: What does `The system just lags` mean?  Are you seeing errors?  What exactly happens, and what exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: it times out and takes too long to load

Answer (score 0):

To make the AJAX call synchronous, just set `async` to `false`:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "liprintednotif.php",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 50000,
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: it shows this in the console:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.